# Javascript does not the true result of Checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, checkbox

I'm working with Javascript to see if a checkbox is checked or not. So I coded this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
    .cb{
        display: inline-block;
        width: 12px;
        height:12px;
        background: #EEE;
        border: 1px solid #999;
        border-radius:1px;
        transition: background 0.2s linear;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function submitValues(){
        alert("cb1 = "+cb1.dataset.checked+"    cb2 = "+cb2.dataset.checked);
    }
    function toggleCB(cb){
        if(cb.dataset.checked == 0){
            cb.style.background = "#89D814";
            cb.style.checked = 1;
        }else{
            cb.style.background = "#EEE";
            cb.dataset.checked = 0;
        }
    }
    </script>
    <div class="cb" id="cb1" data-checked="0" onclick="toggleCB(this)"></div> cb1</br></br>
    <div class="cb" id="cb2" data-checked="0" onclick="toggleCB(this)"></div> cb2</br></br>
    <button onclick="submitValues()">Submit</button>
</body>
```

So if you check the checkbox within this example, after submitting the form, the true value of checkbox must be shown in the popup alert.

But the problem with it is that whenever I try to Submit the form while both checkboxes are checked, I still see the message `cb1 = 0 cb2 = 0` on screen.

Now why is that?

Comment: note: you have **no checkbox** in your html `<input type="checkbox">` is a checkbox, what you have is a "div"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting `cb.style.checked` instead of `cb.dataset.checked`. Updating that would fix the issue.

```
function toggleCB(cb){
    if(cb.dataset.checked == 0){
        cb.style.background = "#89D814";
        cb.dataset.checked = 1;             // << --- This
    }else{
        cb.style.background = "#EEE";
        cb.dataset.checked = 0;
    }
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
    .cb{
        display: inline-block;
        width: 12px;
        height:12px;
        background: #EEE;
        border: 1px solid #999;
        border-radius:1px;
        transition: background 0.2s linear;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function submitValues(){
        alert("cb1 = "+cb1.dataset.checked+"    cb2 = "+cb2.dataset.checked);
    }
    function toggleCB(cb){
        if(cb.dataset.checked == 0){
            cb.style.background = "#89D814";
            cb.dataset.checked = 1; 
        }else{
            cb.style.background = "#EEE";
            cb.dataset.checked = 0;
        }
    }
    </script>
    <div class="cb" id="cb1" data-checked="0" onclick="toggleCB(this)"></div> cb1</br></br>
    <div class="cb" id="cb2" data-checked="0" onclick="toggleCB(this)"></div> cb2</br></br>
    <button onclick="submitValues()">Submit</button>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your toggle function, you do `cb.style.checked = 1;`. It suppose to be `cb.dataset.checked = 1;`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your problem is your if clause.

```
if(cb.dataset.checked == 0)
{
  cb.style.background = "#89D814";
  cb.style.checked = 1;
}
```

You wrote `cb.style.checked` but I guess what you wanted to write was `cb.dataset.checked`